# Parsing of double-quoted words with scala parser

Tags: scala, parsing

I need to parse something like this(including double quotes) - "blablabla"

My class must extend StdTokenParser. And my class has such method:

```
protected lazy val id: Parser[String] = "\"" ~ ident ~ "\"".? ^^ {case a ~ b ~ c => a + b + c}
```

Here ident is a member of StdTokenParsers trait.

And it works good when input is "blablabla (there is only one double-quote), but when the input is "blablabla" it fails during parsing with following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure:     
``"'' expected but "blablabla" found
```

So, can somebody help me?

Comment: What exactly `ident` is implemented to match? And why you made closing quote optional?

Comment: @Łukasz  def ident: Parser[String] =`elem("identifier", _.isInstanceOf[Identifier]) ^^ (_.chars)` I made closing quote optional just for testing. It doesn't influence on results.

Answer (score 1):

`StdTokenParsers` uses `StdTokens` which already tokenizes string literals before parsing.

The error message is because the first token (the entire string literal) doesn't match the first expected token `"`.

You can either use the `stringLit` parser from the `StdTokenParsers` trait and chain it with a parser for the string itself or define your own tokens that don't contain string literals.

Comment: stringLit is not suitable for my case, because I need to parse separately following cases: "case1" and 'case2'. So it should be different behavior of my program if it parse either double quoted identifier or single quoted. Can you explain how to define my own token?